# How do I exclude a source from selection in Paraview?

Tags: paraview

I have two sources open in Paraview. The first is an unstructured VTK grid that defines a surface with data for each of the cells. The second source is a VTK polyline that defines the capacity for the cells.

I am plotting both sets of data to visualize which data points are within the envelope (polyline) and which are outside.

I am new to Paraview and am struggling with selecting data when multiple sources are active. The linked selection between the RenderView and LineChartView works when I have one source active in LineChartView but fails when I have both sources active (see the screenshots below).

I would like to be able to exclude the polyline source from the selection so that when I select points or cells they are highlighted in the other visualization panel. Currently the polyline source appears to be preventing the selection tool from linking selections between the two panels.

If there is a better file format than .vtu and .vtp I am also open to that, but even by adding a programmable filter to the VTU source it breaks the selection tool.

Single Source Selection - Working as intended:
[image: Single Source Selection - Working as intended]

Multiple Source Selection - Selection from left panel is not represented on the right panel:
[image: Multiple Source Selection - Not working as intended]

Comment: You may want to answer to yourself here :)

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to the Paraview forums and after chatting with a developer came to the understanding that the linked selection between the RenderView and ChartView struggles when multiple sources are in play. To workaround this issue I intend to append the envelope data onto the unstructured grid data source so that I am only dealing with a single source rather than multiple sources. A bit hacky but should achieve my goals.

Additional discussion is provided here: https://discourse.paraview.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-a-source-from-selection-in-paraview/4073/8